# whitespaces in the path of windows filepath

Tags: python, file

I am working on file operations using python.

I have a filepath as :

```
filepath = "E:/ABC/SEM 2/testfiles/all.txt"
```

when I am opening the file using python, it says me :

```
IOError: No such file:
```

but, the file is present on the drive.
It may be because windows cannnot take "SEM 2" properly as it contains space.
How can I deal with such whitespaces in the path of window path?

Comment: How are you opening the file? There should be no problem with the space in the name.

Comment: It's not difficult to tell if the problem is the space (but I don't think so): just rename the directory and see if it can find the file

Comment: it is opening the file properly if i select any of the file which doesnt contains such spaces in folder name

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes instead of the basckslash?

Comment: @Raffaele : yes renaming the directory works but in practical case, my program will not able to rename directories which having spaces

Comment: @Frankline actually in the code posted there are only forward slashes...

Comment: @Frankline : no i didnt tried it. i guess windows have this problem of slashes and whitespaces always while programming :(

Comment: Forward slashes work fine. so do spaces. How are you trying to open the file?

Comment: What if you wrap the path in another pair of quotes? That should work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no problem with whitespaces in the path since you're not using the "shell" to open the file. Here is a session from the windows console to prove the point. You're doing something else wrong

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
>>> os.makedirs("C:/ABC/SEM 2/testfiles")
>>> open("C:/ABC/SEM 2/testfiles/all.txt","w")
<open file 'C:/ABC/SEM 2/testfiles/all.txt', mode 'w' at 0x0000000001D95420>
>>> exit()

C:\Users\Gnibbler>dir "C:\ABC\SEM 2\testfiles"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 46A0-BB64

 Directory of c:\ABC\SEM 2\testfiles

13/02/2013  10:20 PM    <DIR>          .
13/02/2013  10:20 PM    <DIR>          ..
13/02/2013  10:20 PM                 0 all.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  78,929,309,696 bytes free

C:\Users\Gnibbler>
```

Answer (score 73):

```
path = r"C:\Users\mememe\Google Drive\Programs\Python\file.csv"
```

Closing the path in r"string" also solved this problem very well.

Comment: Not for me, I use windows 7 + anaconda 3.5

Comment: What will happen if I used single quotes(') instead of double(")? will that work

Comment: what if the string is a variable?

Answer (score 18):

Try putting double quotes in your filepath variable

```
"\"E:/ABC/SEM 2/testfiles/all.txt\""
```

Check the permissions of the file or in any case consider renaming the folder to remove the space

Comment: As gnibbler demonstrated, it isn't the space, and more quotes won't help.

Answer (score 2):

a hack on **Mac**:

```
path = '/Volumes/Public/ABY/Documents/Musiq/slumdog millonaire/Mausam and Escape.mp3'
nPath = path.replace(' ', '\\ ')
print(nPath)
```

Output:

```
/Volumes/Public/ABY/Documents/Musiq/slumdog\ millonaire/Mausam\ and\ Escape.mp3
```

Comment: Simple and easy solution, works perfectly on windows as well

Answer (score 0):

(WINDOWS - AWS solution) 
Solved for windows by putting **tripple quotes around files and paths**.

Benefits:

  1)  Prevents excludes that quietly were getting ignored.

  2)  Files/folders with spaces in them, will no longer kick errors.

```
    aws_command = 'aws s3 sync """D:/""" """s3://mybucket/my folder/"  --exclude """*RECYCLE.BIN/*""" --exclude """*.cab""" --exclude """System Volume Information/*""" '

    r = subprocess.run(f"powershell.exe {aws_command}", shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple hack try adding a **single quote** before the the double quotes like :

```
os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"')
```

worked for me

Answer (score -1):

It works for me

```
import os
```

Set working directory

```
os.chdir("""C:/Users/admin/nht1/OneDrive - quarrycubicle/Desktop/Docs/AI Data Analysis/Tai lieu tham khao""")

os.getcwd()
```

Out[1]: 'C:\Users\admin\nht1\OneDrive - quarrycubicle\Desktop\Docs\AI Data Analysis\Tai lieu tham khao'

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `os.path.expanduser(my_path)` without escaping the white spaces in `my_path`.

If you want to join some subpaths:

```
import os
path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(ROOT, my_path))
```

and check with

```
assert os.path.exists(path)
```

Answer (score -2):

double back slash `\\` will solve the problem

```
subprocess.run('type "C:\\Users\\nameofuser\\blackdrive - somecorp\\Desktop\\seadlines_data.txt"',shell=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use triple quotation marks `"""` as such:

```
filepath = """E:/ABC/SEM 2/testfiles/all.txt"""
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.