# How to allow a filename with whitespace in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, whitespace, filenames

I have a script for importing the contents of csv files in to a database. But when I try

```
filepath = '/Users/mc_kaiser/Desktop/Foo\ 020218-021318.csv'
test = open(filepath)
```

I get an `IOError`:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mc_kaiser/Desktop/Foo\\ 020218-021318.csv'
```

I looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14852140/3071419) and tried some of the answers, but it's Windows specific and didn't answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: Did `filepath = '/Users/mc_kaiser/Desktop/Foo 020218-021318.csv'` not work? (Without the `'\'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `\` for escape is only used by shell, not part of the file name. In Python, just use:

```
filepath = '/Users/mc_kaiser/Desktop/Foo 020218-021318.csv'
```