# Pyspark on windows : Input path does not exist

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark

As I am new to pyspark, I did some research about my issue but none of the solutions worked for me.

I want to read a text file, I first put it in the same folder as my .py file in jupyter notebook. For that I run the following command:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("Parcours client.txt")
print(rdd.collect())
```

I get this error:

```
Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/Data Analysis/Parcours client.txt
```

Although this is exactly where I put the file.txt, and I launch my pyspark from

```
C:/Spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
```

I tried also to indicate the local direction where my txt file exist:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\Jiji\\Desktop\\Data Analysis\\L'Output\\Parcours client.txt")
print(rdd.collect())
```

I get the same error:

```
Input path does not exist: file:/Users/Jiji/Desktop/Data Analysis/L'Output/Parcours client.txt
```

Comment: What happens when you try a simple path with no spaces or special chars, such as `"C:/parcours_client.txt"`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I still get the same error: _Input path does not exist:  file:C:/parcours_client.txt_

Comment: If you have any Idea please Help.

Comment: How do you run `pyspark`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `rdd = sc.textFile("Parcours\ client.txt")` or `rdd = sc.textFile(r"Parcours client.txt")`

See also:
[whitespaces in the path of windows filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852140/)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I run the two commands but still got the same error. I have tried to put my txt file in the Desktop and run the following command  `rdd = sc.textFile('C:\\Users\\Jiji\\Desktop\\Output\\Parcours clients  .txt')` . I think the error was generated because of the spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your help.

I have tried to put my txt file in a folder in the desktop wich the name doesn't have any spaces and that solve my issue. So I run the following command:

`rdd = sc.textFile('C:\\Users\\Jiji\\Desktop\\Output\\Parcours client.txt')`

I think the issue was because of the spaces in the path.