# Giving a path to save my model. (/content/drive/My Drive/training) , but the space in "My Drive" throws an error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I give a path to where I want to store my model that I'm training, the path is like (/content/drive/My Drive/training), but the space in ("My Drive") , it breaks the path from "My" and start a new path from "Drive" Because of the space in "My Drive".
Any solution for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [whitespaces in the path of windows filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852140/whitespaces-in-the-path-of-windows-filepath)

Comment: Please take these guidelines into consideration when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask