# Run shell from python to open a file

Tags: python, shell

Trying to open a file using shell :

```
os.system("G:\Folder\2. Cntry\ACCD.accdb")
```

throw the following error :

```
'G:\Folder.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

However when I paste `"G:\Folder\2. Cntry\ACCD.accdb"` into cmd prompt, it does open the file.

It seems that `\2` is read as a [image] .

but using :

```
os.system(r"G:\Folder\2. Cntry\ACCD.accdb")
```

returns :

```
'G:\Folder\2.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I do ?

Comment: @Cal-cium Sadly, no.. Thank you for trying anyway

Comment: I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14852277/11167163) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the backslash is an escape character in Python, you could:

- Use an raw string: `r"G:\Folder\2. Cntry\ACCD.accdb"`
- Use forward slashes: `"G:/Folder/2. Cntry/ACCD.accdb"`
- Escape the backslashes: `"G:\\Folder\\2. Cntry\\ACCD.accdb"`

Which works for any `subprocess` function.

Using `os.system` you need to pass the path additionally surrounded with single quotes:

```
import os
import subprocess

paths = (
    [r"C:\Temp\2. Cntry\executer.exe", r'"C:\Temp\2. Cntry\executer.exe"'],
    ["C:/Temp/2. Cntry/executer.exe", '"C:/Temp/2. Cntry/executer.exe"'],
    ["C:\\Temp\\2. Cntry\\executer.exe", '"C://Temp//2. Cntry//executer.exe"'],
)

for p1, p2 in paths:
    subprocess.call(p1)
    os.system(p2)
```

Out:

```
Arguments passed:
C:\Temp\2. Cntry\executer.exe
done
Arguments passed:
C:\Temp\2. Cntry\executer.exe
done
Arguments passed:
C://Temp//2. Cntry//executer.exe
done
Arguments passed:
C://Temp//2. Cntry//executer.exe
done
Arguments passed:
C:\Temp\2. Cntry\executer.exe
done
Arguments passed:
C://Temp//2. Cntry//executer.exe
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working to.. same issue. The output is the same as when I use `os.system(r"G:\Folder\2. Cntry\ACCD.accdb")`

Comment: I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14852277/11167163) answer

Answer (score -1):

for your prompt, try to open change the path like this because the space causes the pb.

```
G:\Folder\"2. Cntry"\ACCD.accdb
```