# How to locally serve a jupyterlite environment with xeus-python?

Tags: python, jupyter-kernel, jupyterlite, xeus-python

I'm figuring out how to use set up jupyterlite so that I can share my notebooks and results with others. Currently I use binder for this purpose. I was able to serve jupyter lite with a Pyodide kernel but I keep getting a error when trying to use jupyterlite-xeus-python. To run jupyterlite-xeus-python I'm cloning and running the template repository (https://github.com/jupyterlite/xeus-python-demo). I know the repository should have everything necessary because github actions was able to deploy the repository over here (https://rk22000.github.io/XEUS-Python-demo/lab/index.html) and the deployment works just fine.

The command I'm using

```bash
jupyter lite serve --contents content
```

the error

```bash
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Projects\\XEUS-Python\\_output\\dist\\jupyter-lite.json'
```

Comment: Maybe this is wrong since you say it worked for Pyodide, but I would imagine that error is correct? There is no file at `D:\\Projects\\XEUS-Python\\_output\\dist\\jupyter-lite.json` because it is at `D:\Projects\XEUS-Python\_output\dist\jupyter-lite.json`? I see negative scores with that double quote approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949909/8508004). Did you try other ways to specify the path? Any chance that path stuff gets handled differently with the two deployments and that is causing the difference?